# Fixing Module Not Found with Browserify for Local Relative Requires

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp, browserify, commonjs

I have a demo NPM framework structured as the following:

**./src/child.coffee**

```
module.exports = class Child
```

**./src/parent.coffee**

```
Child = require "./child"
module.exports = class Parent
```

**./gulp.js**

```
require('coffee-script/register');
require('./gulpfile.coffee');
```

**./gulp.coffee**

```
gulp = require "gulp"

util = require "gulp-util"
coffee = require "gulp-coffee"
browserify = require "gulp-browserify"

gulp.task "build", ->
  gulp.src("./src/**/*.coffee")
    .pipe(coffee().on("error", util.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./lib/"))
```

Everything works great if I run `gulp build`. However, I'm trying to introduce Browserify by adding the following to the **build** task:

```
gulp.task "build", ->
  gulp.src("./src/**/*.coffee")
    .pipe(coffee().on("error", util.log))
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./lib/"))
```

With that in place the relative requires within the framework fail:

> events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^ Error: module "./child" not found from "/Users/kevin/Desktop/demo/src/fake_d1543b04.js"   at notFound
>   (/Users/kevin/Desktop/demo/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/index.js:803:15)
>   at
>   /Users/kevin/Desktop/demo/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/index.js:754:23
>   at
>   /Users/kevin/Desktop/demo/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:185:24
>   at
>   /Users/kevin/Desktop/demo/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:36:22
>   at load
>   (/Users/kevin/Desktop/demo/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:54:43)
>   at
>   /Users/kevin/Desktop/demo/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:60:22
>   at
>   /Users/kevin/Desktop/demo/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:16:47
>   at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)

How does one properly setup relative requires within a framework and have it work with gulp and coffeescript? Changing the require to be for a dependency from the `package.json` (i.e. `Lodash = require "lodash"`) allows gulp to build. Furthermore changing from coffeescript to regular javascript also fixes the problem.

Comment: did you try this: `export default class Child`?!

Comment: I did not. Is `export default` a part of `ES6`?

Comment: @KevinSylvestre Yes, `export default` is part of the ES 2015 module syntax.

Comment: @KevinSylvestre You actually have multiple entry files for the same bundle? Also, are you using / going to be using gulp for anything beyond what's illustrated here (within the `build` task)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely the `.coffee` extension. You need to instruct browserify to look for that extension. See [`opts.extensions`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/8d1113cf62ff73ee5758209d8f1d45ff5b1f513c/readme.markdown#browserifyfiles--opts). I don't know how you'd do that with gulp-browserify, but you're better off not using it anyway (it's blacklisted by gulp, if that matters to you, and I believe it's unmaintained).